# Travis-CI: Artifacts uploading does not work for PR builds

Tags: travis-ci, artifacts

I configured Travis-CI artifacts uploading by following https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/uploading-artifacts/,  it works fine for regular build triggered by push/merge, but is not triggered for the Pull Requests build. I have set "addons.artifacts.debug" to true", for the regular push builds, I can see all the debugging informations, such as

> 1495 Uploading Artifacts (BETA)
>   1496 artifacts revision=e2af40fea0aa0229ff1f26e932e018c71e95bb91
>   1498 artifacts upload
>   1499 DEBUG: setting log level to debug

However, for the PR triggered builds, I do not see any information related to addon.

Any idea how to upload artifacts for PR triggered builds?

Thanks!

Comment: That's by-design for security purposes.